# Passing props as unknown attributes to an element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right now I'm working on an Input component which will represent a form input field. I want it to be universal (like for text, date and numbers). The problem so far is that I don't know how to pass unknown attributes directly to my input element Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Input extends Component {
    render () {
      let required = false
      if (this.props.required) {
        required = true
      }
      return (
        <div className='form-group'>
          <label>{ this.props.label }</label>
          <input 
            type={this.props.type} 
            name={this.props.name}
            value={this.props.value} 
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            className={this.props.className} 
            onChange={this.props.handleChange}
            {this.props.attrs}  // error here
            required = {required} 
          />
        </div>
      )
    }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  attrs: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  required: PropTypes.bool
}

Input.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  required: true
}

export default Input
```

React rejects `this.props.attrs` when I insert it directly into the `input` element and I don't know what to do...

**Why do I even need this.props.attrs?**

I don't know what input type I may want to use in the future. Let's say I want to have a number input. In this case in `this.props.attrs` I could store `min = '1' max = '100'` string.

So when I pass `this.props.attrs` to a component I want to get an input like the following:

```
<input ... min = '1' max = '100' ... />
```

Comment: have you tried: {{this.props.attrs}}?

Comment: @MarouenMhiri isnt this an angular syntax? :)

Comment: @Sag1v: no because you can do somthing like that in React :  <span style={{color: 'red'}}> ;-). When passing an object lateral, you use double curley braces in React

Comment: then what makes you think `{{this.props.attrs}}` this is a valid object literal? where is the key and where is the value? :)

Comment: just ask John if it works

Comment: @MarouenMhiri, double curly braces don't work in this case

Comment: @JohnAward of course it won't work.  it's an easy fix you forgot to spread the object (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [object spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) `{...this.props.attrs}`
Note that this is a proposal and its on stage 3 at the moment.

Here is a running example:

```js
class MyInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { title, ...restOfProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{title}</label>
        <input {...restOfProps} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyInput title="password" type="password" style={{border:'3px solid green', margin:'0 5px'}} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to mention here:

- You need to spread `rest` of attributes
- Set `attr` as object on `PropTypes`
- If you want to make some props `required` then this implementation is fine but if you don't then you can eliminate PropTypes restriction and refactor the component to get only

`{label, ...rest} = this.props;`

```js
let { PropTypes, Component } = React;

class Input extends Component {
 render () {
    let { required, label, handleChange, ...restOfattrs } = this.props;
    required = required ? required : false;
      
      return (
        <div className='form-group'>
          <label>{label}</label>
          <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          {...restOfattrs}
          required={required} /> 
        </div>
      )
    }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  attrs: PropTypes.object,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  required: PropTypes.bool
}

Input.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  required: true
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Input label="Type password : " className="input" type="password" placeholder="Type Password" handleChange={() => console.log('change...')}  maxLength={4} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.input{
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px 40px; 
    background: #e7e7e7;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"> </div>
```